# Swipe-select on a GridView Item in MVVM

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have a GridView where I want to be able to swipe-select the items or click on them.

As I wanted to work with MVVM the Click was handled by a Command on a Button which is the root of any item in the GridView.

In the following a simplified example of this:

```
<GridView
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GroupedItemsViewSource}}"
    IsSwipeEnabled="True"
    Padding="116,0,40,46">
    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Command="{Binding ClickedCommand}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

My problem is that the swipe won't be recognized as long as I have the Button in the ItemTemplate. So the Command on the Button seems to receive all gestures and doesn't allow to swipe-select the item. When i

Doesn anyone have the same problem or an idea how to solve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd avoid using buttons in `GridViewItem`s since they have conflicting input handling. Simply put your content there instead of in the button. The way I'd use it would be to handle `ItemClick` events, get the `DataContext` from the event sender (probably `GridViewItem`) to get the item view model and invoke the command from the event handler. If you really dislike code behind - you can look up ["gridview itemclick command"](http://www.bing.com/search?q=gridview%20itemclick%20command) with your favorite search engine and you might find some [attached behavior](http://www.apeoholic.se/post/gridview-ItemClick-Command.aspx) that allows to bind commands to the event.